# Submit the options in the selected order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is submitting some options from a dropdown list, but when I do, I want to send the options in the order they are selected.
Currently, it submits the array of the selection, but in the order they are in the dropdown list. How can I change that?
This is the html code for the dropdown:

```js
< select style = "padding: 1em;"
name = "skills"
multiple = ""
id = "uInput"
class = "ui fluid dropdown" >
    <
    option value = "" > Skills < /option> <
    option value = "java" > JAVA < /option> <
    option value = "matlab" > MATLAB < /option> <
    option value = "embedded" > Embedded < /option> <
    option value = "mech" > Mechanical Engineering < /option> <
    option value = "ccpp" > C / C++ < /option> <
    option value = "elec" > ELEC < /option> <
    option value = "hwdev" > HW DEV < /option> <
    /select>
```

The JavaScript code I have on it

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});


$("#uInput").on(
    'change',
    function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
            $('.item').addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $('.item').toggleClass('disabled', false);
        }
    });
```

I did this to allow the user to select only 3 options.

To better understand what I am saying, here is an example:
If my selected options are : Embedded, Java, Elec it will submit Java, Embedded, Elec ...and I don't want that.

Comment: You can build the list of selected items by having an array that you push new values to, when the user selects a skill.  However, I would *strongly* advise against this as it sounds like a user nightmare.  Imagine if your user decided they'd selected in the wrong order.  They'd have to clear the list and start again.  Also, what if the user doesn't realise that selection order is relevant?  If it were me I'd have a list of available skills in a listbox and add them to a listbox of selected skills when clicked, and also allow the user to re-order them at will.

Comment: There is no such built-in functionality, you need to track list of selected options by yourself

Comment: I tried a lot of methods but without any success. I am not that experienced in this area...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("select").select2({
    tags : true
});
$("select").on("select2:select", function(evt) {

    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);

    $element.detach();
    $(this).append($element);
    $(this).trigger("change");


});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemsArray = [];

$("option").select(function() {
  itemsArray.push[this.property];      
});
```

Then send the array to the server.

Replace 'property' with whatever you want to send on select, but bear in mind if the user changes their mind later it's going to get messy.

You might want to give your options a common class too, or select by child.

Comment: I think this is a little short of what you’d call actually working. A click means not only selection of an option, but also de-selection of an already selected option, Your code would simply push the option property to the array in both cases ... and continue to do so if the process is repeated several times.